# Moving/Hiding a button in vpython

Tags: python, graphics, vpython

How do I hide a button or simply move it off the screen in VPython?
I have tried:

```
 del button
 button.visible = False
 button.pos.x = 500 # well off the screen
```

None of those seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Open Lib\site-packages\vis\controls.py(in your python folder). Find the button class. Insert this function at the bottom.

```
class button(ctrl):
...
  def _set_visible(self,value):
    self.box1.visible = value
    self.box2.visible = value
    self.box3.visible = value
    self.box4.visible = value
    self.button.visible = value
    self.label.visible = value
  def _get_visible(self):
    return self.box1.visible
  visible =property(_get_visible,_set_visible)
```